# How to bind data to chart in winforms and refresh chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, controls

I tried to bind chart to `generatedSequence` of type `List<float>`. How to update chart control after binding?

I tried this but with no luck:

```
chart1.DataSource = new BindingList<float>(chartSequence);
chart1.DataBind();

chart1.Update();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't forget set DataSource property of Series in chart property.

[image]

Set `XValueMember` and `YValueMembers` from code:

```
chart1.Series.First().XValueMember = "X";
chart1.Series.First().YValueMembers = "Y";
```

[Tutorial: Creating a Basic Chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489237.aspx)

Comment: How to specify that float type of list is XValueMember? in code?, for example: `chart1.Series.First().XValueMember = ????;`

Comment: @testCoder check my answer again.