# Visual studio c# pie chart will not redraw

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am using winforms and attempting to create a pie chart which will update on a button click. I have added two points to the charts series via the designer. I am sure the values of the points are being changed however the chart itself is not updating to show this.

```
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[0].SetValueY(results["TimeFrame1"].Count);
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[1].SetValueY(results["TimeFrame2"].Count);
```

This updates the two points. I have tried calling `chart1.update()` however it did not redraw the chart. Is there some method I am not aware of to make the chart redraw. Thanks

Comment: Maybe `chart1.Invalidate()` or `chart1.Refresh()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manually setting your points inside your series, why not use databinding? That way whenever the underlying data source changes, your chart will change too. Here is another SO answer with some additional info:

[How to bind data to chart in winforms and refresh chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347454/how-to-bind-data-to-chart-in-winforms-and-refresh-chart)

Alternatively, try calling chart1.Refresh() instead of chart1.Update().